# Google AdSense critical error (page unresponsive, this page is slowing down)

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

Whenever I enable Google Ads on my website (i.e., the problem disappears after I remove Google Ads script), I get the following after a minute:

[image]

After pressing Stop, the following is displayed in the console:

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem? I have tried looking inside the Google Ads script referenced in this message, but it is compressed and impossible to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/174974866/pages-with-adsense-auto-ads-unresponsive?hl=en

It's the Anchor ads that causes the problem. Switch it off and it will load.

Maybe Widescreen mode of ancor ads but I'll have to wait and see (like the link above)

Comment: You're a lifesaver!! I spent so much time now trying to fix this. It is a shame, however, since anchor ads were my preferred type.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Is there any solution for this? I realy need the anchor ad to be enabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if you include the side rail ads as well the problem is resolved! This may help as fixing this problem is difficult.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).